# Determine $z=x+iy$ such that $\cot(z)=1+i$ .

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Determine $z=x+iy$ such that $\cot(z)=1+i$ .

I tried to use the arctangent after using the following formula, but I'm not sure if I did the right thing:
$\mathrm{arccot}(z)=\frac{1}{2i}\ln\left(\frac{z+i}{z-i}\right)$. (Then I expressed the logarithm function of the complex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong formula (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Logarithmic_forms)). It should be:
$$\text{arccot} \ z = \frac{i}{2} \ln \left( \frac{z-i}{z+i} \right)$$

so $z = \text{arccot}(1+i) = \frac{i}{2} \ln(\frac{1}{1+2i})$.

Now remember that the principal value of $\ln u$ is  $\ln |u| + i \ \text{Arg} \ u$.

Comment: FYI, your formula and the OP's are actually basically the same, just expressed differently. Using $\ln\left(\frac{x}{y}\right) = -\ln\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$, you have $\frac{i}{2}\ln\left(\frac{z-i}{z+i}\right) = \frac{-i}{2}\ln\left(\frac{z+i}{z-i}\right) = \frac{-i(i)}{2i}\ln\left(\frac{z+i}{z-i}\right) = \frac{1}{2i}\ln\left(\frac{z+i}{z-i}\right)$.

Comment: I have seen the OP's formula, but I couldn't remember if the signs as displayed in the question were correct, so I stuck to the Wikipedia version instead.